# passing variable to a class

Tags: php, inheritance

This is the scenario:

There are 3 classes: **class A, class B , class C**

```
//A.php
class A {
 public $something1;
 public $something2;
 //long list....

// i am the base class
}


//B.php
class B extends A {

// i am a child of A
}


//C.php
class C extends A{

// i do the side work
}
```

The program makes an object and sets values for **class B** like this:

```
$b = new B();
$b->something1 = "XYZ";
$b->something2 = "ABC";
...... long list.....
```

Now what I want is:
I want to call some functions of `class C` in `class B`.
I know I can do that by making an object in `class B` like this `$c = new C();`.

But I also want to pass all the variables of `B` i.e. **(something1, something2 ....)**
passed by the program to `class C`

I know I can do this like this:

```
$c->something1 = $this->something1;
$c->something2 = $this->something2 .....
```

But is it possible to do that without the above code because
`$c->somethingN` will just take too many lines and i do not like repetitive code.

I just want to know if there is any other way.

Comment: Why not use an array of values instead of individual members? Then you can handle all variables as one. Alternatively make an additional 'container' class for the values, so that you can handle and pass them around more easily. And, actually, you already _have_ the values you set in class B available in class C, since you declared them as public in class A which is rderived by both, class B and C...

Comment: The idea of container class looks interesting , can you give an example ?

Comment: Just a class "Storage" or something acting like a passive container. You create an instance in one class and pass it to other objects as a reference to that instance. That's all.

Comment: Why don't you inherit B from C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know i can do that by making an object in class B like this $c = new C();.

If this are instance members (not static), this is the way to go.

---

Another way would be to use static members, like this:

```
class A {
    public static $foo;
}

class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

# usage:
B::$foo = 'bar';
echo C::$foo; // will output 'bar'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , i cannot make it static because that will have huge changes in the code . I will be going with my old idea

Comment: Ok. There are several ways to achive what you want. But inheritance will not fit (if not static members). Would need to see your application to give advices.